# How do I pass three arrays from on method to another?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method studentSummary, that scans the input and creates three arrays examMark,courseworkMark and courseworkWeight. I need these arrays passing over to a different method, so I can use them to calculate moduleResult.

heres my code:

```
public static int[] studentSummary(int[] courseworkWeight2, int [] examMark2 , int [] courseworkMark2){

    int examMark[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int courseworkMark[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    Scanner resultInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int courseworkWeight[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    for (int k = 1; k < 7; k++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter exam marks for module " + k + ":");
        examMark[k - 1] = resultInput.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter Coursework marks for module " + k
                + ":");
        courseworkMark[k - 1] = resultInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter Coursework weighting for module "
                + k + ":");
        courseworkWeight[k - 1] = resultInput.nextInt();


    }
```

Calculator method:

```
public static int[] markCalculator() {

int[] courseworkWeight = new int [6];
int[] courseworkMark = new int [6];
int[] examMark = new int [6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        computedModuleMark = ((courseworkMark[i] * courseworkWeight[i]) + (examMark[i] * (100 - courseworkWeight[i]))) / 100;


        if ((computedModuleMark) < 35) {
            if (examMark[i]<35){

            }
        }

        moduleMark[i] = computedModuleMark;

    }


    computeResult(moduleMark);
    StudentChart.draw(moduleMark);
    StudentChart.printSummary(moduleMark);
    return moduleMark;

}
```

Comment: Yes exactly if you want people to consider your problem you should make it easy for them (clear your code from unneccessary comments)

Comment: After you choose a solution that solved your problem please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `markCalculator()` with `markCalculator(int[] courseworkWeight, int [] examMark , int [] courseworkMark)` and remove declaration of these variables from the method.
2. Call `markCalculator(courseworkWeight, examMark, courseworkMark)` in `studentSummary()`

I guess that it's studentSummary that shoudn't take any arguments. Is it so that your copy paste gone wrong by swapping signatures of these methods?

Other possibility is that your source had these arrays as global variable (outside of methods, in the same file) and both methods had no arguments - method().

Answer (score 0):

You can either :

1.declare the arrays as class fields and just call the function 
`markCalculator(int[] courseworkWeight2, int [] examMark2 , int [] courseworkMark2)`  
2. call `markCalculator(courseworkWeight, examMark, courseworkMark)` from studentSummary() 
3. return them in a list from the function studentSummary(...)

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>().addAll(courseworkWeight2,examMark2,courseworkMark2);
```

and pass the list by calling `markCalculator(List<Object>);`